# Does Azure App Configuration support some kind of persistence for an on-prem application?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-app-configuration

I'm looking into using Azure app config (AAC) for an existing on-prem asp.net (.NET 6) app to allow for dynamic updates to the config. I am wondering if AAC will work for my situation though.

My main concern is that any config updates made in AAC are persisted somehow in case we lose connection to AAC. So the app needs to have an on-prem location to pull the most current config in case that connection is lost.

Basically, I do not want the app to revert to an older config if the connection is lost and the app pool is recycled, but that seems to be what would most likely happen based on my understanding of it.

So, I need a way to persist the config after any update, even if the app pool is recycled. Is this something that Microsoft addresses somehow?

The only thing I found that seemed like it had potential to be a solution was in the AAC Best Practices documentation, under "Client Applications in App Configuration".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-best-practices

They suggest a proxy server for security and traffic reasons there. I was thinking that an on-prem proxy server could potentially work for this as well if it could persist the latest config. I couldn't find any details in the documentation on how to set such a proxy up though.

Is there some solution to this that I'm missing, or is AAC just not suitable for my situation?

Comment: ...why not just write the few lines of custom-code needed to save AAC-source config settings to local-disk and reload from that if AAC can't be contacted?

Comment: In _"client Applications in App Configuration"_ - by "client application" they're referring to _your_ clients of _your_ applications, not that your ASP.NET application is a client (because it isn't).

Comment: Right, I understand that it wasn't referring to my app as a client, and that they were recommending it for security and traffic purposes for actual clients. My concern with simply writing the updated configuration to the file is that the service runs on multiple servers, so the instances could potentially remain out of sync for an extended period if the Azure connection is lost. With a proxy, it would get the updated configuration on the first call to it, and then any subsequent calls from other instances would also get that configuration.

Comment: _"so the instances could potentially remain out of sync for an extended period if the Azure connection is lost."_ - This isn't an issue if the consumers/clients/etc cache the settings from AAC locally on-disk like I just described above, so there is no need for a proxy service at all - nor any benefit (not to mention the effort required to maintain yet another piece of infrastructure that could fail and take down all those consumers with it).

Comment: Scenario: Instance 1 and 2 get the updated configuration and cache locally on disk. Azure connection is lost. Instance 3 attempts to get configuration but can't connect, so continues to use its existing config. --- I need some sort of local shared source for the config that can be used if Azure is unreachable. A fileshare could be used potentially, if locking issues are handled. Otherwise I'd probably need to go to a database I think.

Comment: I think you're overstating the significance of the problem and have tunnel-visioin focused on this proxy-server approach without considering other approaches - for example, why not have the instances communicate directly with each other to share the most-recently-updated version of config between them? And how bad is it, really, if a single instance has stale config?

Comment: I'm open to other options, which is why I was throwing out ideas like the fileshare or database. Having them communicate with each other directly sounds like it would be more difficult than implementing a proxy that they would all use. It could be quite bad if one had a stale config, as it may not allow a new client app to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you worry about the stability of your on-prem infrastructure, the availability of Azure App Configuration (AAC) is equally important to applications regardless of whether they run in the cloud or on-prem. AAC put huge effort into ensuring high availability. You may check out this [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/faq#how-does-app-configuration-ensure-high-data-availability) for details.

1. The availability zone (AZ) resiliency is automatically enabled for all AAC stores without extra charge for regions with AZ support.
2. You are recommended to [enable the geo-replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-geo-replication) of your AAC store and allow your application to fail over among replicas. It can enhance your application's resiliency against transient and regional outages. See [Resiliency and Disaster Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/concept-disaster-recovery) for more information.

Note that if you use the AAC configuration provider library in your application, it has built-in caching and refreshing functionalities. It will always serve configuration from the cache even if it fails to connect to AAC to refresh the data. It will keep trying to refresh the data (or failover to a different replica if you have geo-replication enabled).

The above should be good enough for most applications. You shouldn't need to build a proxy service that's to solve a different problem. Actually, a proxy service can also fail regardless of where you run it. If you really need an extra layer of protection, you can, for example, export data to a configuration file using AAC Azure CLI as part of your build or CI/CD process and deploy that configuration file as part of your application. This way, your application can use a "last known good" configuration if it can't connect to AAC at startup. Once it can connect to AAC, it can load the latest configuration.